# Export AWS EC2 details to xlsx/csv using boto3 and python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am new to python and boto3.

I need to get the below details using python, I was using bash to get these details.

```
#!/bin/bash
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value,InstanceId,InstanceType,Platform,State.Name,PrivateIpAddress,PublicIpAddress,Placement.AvailabilityZone]" --output text  --region me-south-1 >> aws_ec2_details_me_south_1.xlsx

aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --query "LoadBalancers[*].[LoadBalancerArn,DNSName,LoadBalancerName,Type,Scheme,State.Code]" --output text --region me-south-1 >> aws_elb_details_me_south_1.xlsx

aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query "AutoScalingGroups[*].[AutoScalingGroupName,AutoScalingGroupARN,MinSize,MaxSize,DesiredCapacity,DefaultCooldown]" --output text --region me-south-1 >> aws_autoscaling_me_south_1.xlsx

aws ec2 describe-addresses --query "Addresses[*].[Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value,PublicIp,PrivateIpAddress]" --output text --region me-south-1 >> aws_eip_list_me_south_1.xlsx

aws rds describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier,DBInstanceClass,Engine,EngineVersion,DBInstanceStatus,MasterUsername,Endpoint.Address,MultiAZ,AllocatedStorage,PreferredBackupWindow,BackupRetentionPeriod,StorageEncrypted]" --output text --region me-south-1 >>  aws_rds_details_me_south_1.xlsx
```

I had done some sample python script here,

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default',region_name='me-south-1')
ec2_des = session.client('ec2')
resp = ec2_des.describe_instances(
    Filters = [ {
        'Name' : 'instance-state-name',
        'Values' : [ 'running' ]
        } ]
    )
for i in resp:
    print i(instance-id)
    print (i.image-id)
```

Getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t4.py", line 11, in <module>
    print (i.instance-id)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'instance'
```

Please help me to complete this, with understanding

We have an 80+ AWS account, The main agenda is to run the script to fetch the data from 80+ accounts in a single shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code to fetch details of single EC2 instance and write output to CSV file.

```
import boto3
import csv

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default', region_name='us-east-1')

ec2 = session.client('ec2')

result = []
response = ec2.describe_instances(
    InstanceIds=[
        'i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ]).get('Reservations')

for item in response:
    for each in item['Instances']:
        result.append({
            'ImageId': each['ImageId'],
            'InstanceType': each['InstanceType'],
            'PublicIp': each['PublicIpAddress'],
            'PrivateIp': each['PrivateIpAddress']
        })
#The result type will be list of dictionary.
# print(result) [{'ImageId': 'ami-08c5e20f0xxxxxxxx', 'InstanceType': 't2.micro', 'PublicIp': '10.200.101.11', 'PrivateIp': '172.31.33.95'}]

# Write to csv file.
header = ['ImageId', 'InstanceType', 'PublicIp', 'PrivateIp']
with open('ec2-details.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=header)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(result)
```

Hope it will help you to proceed further.

You can use below code to loop through multiple AWS accounts using switch role.

```
    import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

# master account
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default', region_name='eu-central-1')
iam = session.resource('iam')

accounts = [111111111111, 222222222222, 333333333333]


def assume_role(account: str) -> dict:
    sts_client = session.client('sts')
    try:
        response = sts_client.assume_role(RoleArn=f'arn:aws:iam::{account}:<role-name>',
                                          RoleSessionName=f'dev-{account}-session'
                                          )
        temp_credentials = response['Credentials']
    except ClientError as ex:
        print('Client Error', str(ex))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    return temp_credentials


def list_users(session_arg: dict, acct: int) -> dict:
    iam_user = session.client('iam',
                              aws_access_key_id=session_arg['AccessKeyId'],
                              aws_secret_access_key=session_arg['SecretAccessKey'],
                              aws_session_token=session_arg['SessionToken']
                              )
    # listing users
    response = iam_user.list_users()
    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        for acct in accounts:
            sessionCredentials = assume_role(acct)
            user_info = list_users(sessionCredentials, acct)
            print(user_info)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks @saranjeet singh, this helps me lot

Comment: As mentioned, you have 80+ accounts. how is your set up ? login into one master account and switch role from there? If yes, then I could help you with sample code how you can can access multiple accounts using loop.

Comment: @MohamedJawad I have updated my answer. For example,You can list users from multiple accounts using switch role. You can update function with required operation. Hope now you will accept my answer.

Comment: how I can print the tag values here,

Comment: list_user() will not return Tags. so you have to use get_user(). `response = iam.get_user(UserName='test1')`

Comment: Thanks@ saranjeet singh, for the quick support, I appreciate. actually am looking for the EC2 instance Tag. In AWS Cli we use - Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value same in here

Answer (score 1):

The `describe_instances` method actually returns a dictionnary, for which you can't use a dot "." to access values.

By taking a look at the method's documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) and scrolling down a little bit, you will see a **Returns** part with the **Response Syntax**.

Based on this, if you want to print the instance-id and the image-id using the response of `describe_instances`, you could use this code :

```py
for r in resp['Reservations']:
    for i in r['Instances']:
        print(f" instance id : {i['InstanceId']}")
        print(f" image id :    {i['ImageId']}")
```

#### output

```py
instance id : i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
image id :    ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
instance id : i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
image id :    ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
...
```

Comment: Thanks @vgalin, to make me understand my mistake

Comment: Hi@vgalin, what is "f", here  print(f"

Comment: f'strings are used to format strings. for example
 `name='Mohamed'
 print(f'Your name is {name}')`
 it will print : Your name is Mohamed.